# bluetoothctl and scan and no result

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I deleted my question and ask new question with new **approch**.
I can't find any devices (mobile, headset ) with `bluetoothctl` command.According to [Scan, Pair, Connect to Bluetooth device from Ubuntu from command line using bluetoothctl](https://www.lynxbee.com/scan-pair-connect-to-bluetooth-device-from-ubuntu-from-command-line-using-bluetoothctl/) and [Bluetooth headset (Arch wiki)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset). I have bluetooth in my laptop :

```
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 38:59:F9:42:98:34 debian [default]
```

BTW, I couldn't scan with `blueman`.

```
root@debian:~# /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
Starting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.

[bluetooth]# show
Controller 38:59:F9:42:98:34 (public)
    Name: debian
    Alias: debian
    Class: 0x001c010c
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: yes
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0532
    Discovering: yes

[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 38:59:F9:42:98:34 Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# devices 
Device D0:13:FD:FC:D3:B2 LG Stylus2 Dual
Device F4:7B:5E:40:DC:2A TVBluetooth
```

LG Stylus 2 discovered before by `gnome-control-center`.
My headset is Samsung Level U.

Comment: Is your adapter on? (bluetoothctl 'show' cmd -> please include result in your post). Did you do 'scan on' in bluetoothctl? Are your peripheral devices in discoverable mode? Is your adapter in BR/EDR mode and not restricted to BLE?

Comment: I updated my post. @VincentAchard

Comment: If I understand: your controller scans some devices (LG Stylus2, TVBluetooth) but not your Samsung headset. What makes you think the problem comes from your laptop? From what I see, I would be tempted to incriminate the headset...(?)

Comment: No, LG stylus2 detected by `gnome-control-center`  and is cached.TVBlutooth detect by `blueman` ,`bluetoothctl` couldn't detect anything. @VincentAchard

Comment: Ok. If you have multiple programs dealing with bluetooth, it's gonna be hard to narrow down the problem. (it's already difficult when you have only bluez/bluetoothctl).... Cut off what's not bluez.  I would be surprised that gnome (blueman/control-center) did not rely on bluez... Even Android or Espressif did not bother to rebuild a complete bluetooth stack!